# Necesito hacer convivir bootstrap/3.3.6, jquery2.2.0 con jquery-1.12.4. y jquery-ui.js para utilizar datepicker.de jquery-ui

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui, conflictos

No consigo que el siguiente código me funcione correctamente si no comentó la linea de https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">.

Lo que estoy haciendo es una prueba que debo incluir en una aplicación que ya está utilizando boostrap y esta versión de jquery.

Quiero incluir el datepicker de jquery-ui con boostrap 3.3.6 y no lo consigo.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>jQuery UI Datepicker and Boostrap not working ok</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 
 <!-- Si comentó la siguiente linea si funciona correcto el datepicker  pero necesito que conviva con esta version de jquery porque estoy tocando una
      aplicación que lo utiliza 
 -->
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
 <script>
 var RANGO_DIAS=30;   // 30 ultmos días

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* Limite de fechas por defecto      */
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 function limitePorDefecto(){
  var hoy = new Date();
  var hacedias = new Date();
  hacedias.setDate(hacedias.getDate() - RANGO_DIAS);
  $("#dpFechaMinima").val(fmtFecha4(hacedias));
  $("#dpFechaMaxima").val(fmtFecha4(hoy));
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* Formatear fecha tipo date  en formato dd/MM/YYYY      */
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 function fmtFecha4(fecha){
  
  dia=fecha.getDate();
  mes=fecha.getMonth()+1; // porque todos los meses empiezan por 0
  
  dia=String("00" + dia).slice(-2); // returns 01
  mes=String("00" + mes).slice(-2); // returns 01
  
  anio=fecha.getFullYear();
  return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio;
 }  
 </script>
 
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
 
 // Establece un limite por defecto de 30 dias
 limitePorDefecto();
 
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
   closeText: 'Cerrar',
   prevText: '< Mes anterior',
   nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
   currentText: 'Hoy',
   monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
   dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
   weekHeader: 'Sm',
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   firstDay: 1,
   isRTL: false,
   showMonthAfterYear: false,
   yearSuffix: '',
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true,
   //showOn: "button",
   //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
   //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
   //buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: "",
   buttonImageOnly: false,
   buttonText: ""
   
  };

 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

    

  // Por defecto se muestra un dia con LIMITE_POR_DEFECTO


$("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker( {
      onSelect: function(fecha) {
       var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").da
             var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");
       console.log ("fecha onSelect:" + fecha) 
      }
  }).on("change", function() {
     var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");
    console.log ("fecha:" + fecha)
    if( !fecha){
      limitePorDefecto();
    } else {
     fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + RANGO_DIAS);
     $("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
    } 
  });
  
// Maxima fecha del limite máximo es la fecha actual

$("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    },
    maxDate: new Date()
  }).on("change", function() {
    console.log("Change event");
  });


  
});
</script>

</head>
 
<body>
 

  <div id="contenedorSeleccion" class="container">
       
            <div class="row">
              
             <div class="control-group col-md-2">
             <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="control-label">DESDE FECHA</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                   </label>
                   <input id="dpFechaMinima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"    />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group col-md-2">
             <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="control-label">HASTA FECHA</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                   </label>
                   <input id="dpFechaMaxima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"  />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
   
             

             
            </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo, por qué dos jquery (2.2.0 y 1.12.4)? Además que tiene que ver bootstrap con todo eso? Podrías explicar un poco más detalladamente en problema que se está presentando? por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Es recomendable no utilizar más de una versión de jquery, he eliminado las múltiples versiones que tenías dejando la más reciente en tu código.

**2)** Es importante que para cargar el js de bootstrap siempre se cargue antes el js asociado al jquery.

**3)** Si por algún motivo la eliminación de la librería antigua de jquery genera errores en una aplicación de legado (legacy code) deberías intentar depurar que está generando error ya que generalmente los cambios entre versiones (en tu caso son cercanas ambas versiones de jquery) son muy pequeños y fáciles de depurar.

**4)** No es bueno forzar a la convivencia de dos librerías de jquery en tu aplicación ya que generalmente una sóla es "pesada" además de la evidente duplicidad del código que esto genera. También imposibilita en cierta medida la depuración y optimización de tu código.

A continuación está tu ejemplo funcionando con los cambios que te he comentado:

```js
var RANGO_DIAS=30;   // 30 ultmos días

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* Limite de fechas por defecto      */
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 function limitePorDefecto(){
  var hoy = new Date();
  var hacedias = new Date();
  hacedias.setDate(hacedias.getDate() - RANGO_DIAS);
  $("#dpFechaMinima").val(fmtFecha4(hacedias));
  $("#dpFechaMaxima").val(fmtFecha4(hoy));
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /* Formatear fecha tipo date  en formato dd/MM/YYYY      */
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 function fmtFecha4(fecha){
  
  dia=fecha.getDate();
  mes=fecha.getMonth()+1; // porque todos los meses empiezan por 0
  
  dia=String("00" + dia).slice(-2); // returns 01
  mes=String("00" + mes).slice(-2); // returns 01
  
  anio=fecha.getFullYear();
  return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio;
 }  
 
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
 // Establece un limite por defecto de 30 dias
 limitePorDefecto();
 
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
   closeText: 'Cerrar',
   prevText: '< Mes anterior',
   nextText: 'Mes Siguiente >',
   currentText: 'Hoy',
   monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Juv','Vie','Sab'],
   dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sa'],
   weekHeader: 'Sm',
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   firstDay: 1,
   isRTL: false,
   showMonthAfterYear: false,
   yearSuffix: '',
   showOtherMonths: true,
   selectOtherMonths: true,
   //showOn: "button",
   //Lo comentado es porque se utiliza CSS para poder el icono
   //buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
   //buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: "",
   buttonImageOnly: false,
   buttonText: ""
   
  };

 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);  

  // Por defecto se muestra un dia con LIMITE_POR_DEFECTO


$("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker( {
      onSelect: function(fecha) {
       var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").da
             var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");
       console.log ("fecha onSelect:" + fecha) 
      }
  }).on("change", function() {
     var fecha = $("#dpFechaMinima").datepicker("getDate");
    console.log ("fecha:" + fecha)
    if( !fecha){
      limitePorDefecto();
    } else {
     fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + RANGO_DIAS);
     $("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
    } 
  });
  
// Maxima fecha del limite máximo es la fecha actual

$("#dpFechaMaxima").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + ", Current Selected Value= " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    },
    maxDate: new Date()
  }).on("change", function() {
    console.log("Change event");
  });


  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>jQuery UI Datepicker and Boostrap not working ok</title>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
 
<body>
  <div id="contenedorSeleccion" class="container">
       
            <div class="row">
              
             <div class="control-group col-md-2">
             <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="control-label">DESDE FECHA</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="dpFechaMinima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                   </label>
                   <input id="dpFechaMinima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"    />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group col-md-2">
             <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="control-label">HASTA FECHA</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="dpFechaMaxima" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                   </label>
                   <input id="dpFechaMaxima" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"   maxlength="10" size="10px"  />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
   
             

             
            </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Observación:** Siguiendo estrictamente tu requerimiento (no recomendado por lo que te comenté antes) ya organicé tu código con todos los cambios y para hacer "convivir" ambas versiones solo hace falta que descomentes la siguiente línea en el código que te suministré:

```
<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>-->
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!